# C++ Permutations of a string that outputs results less than or equal to the length of the string

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there a way that I can use permutations to also give results that are less then the string wanting permutations for?

Example, if the users enters a string of characters, lets say "dvoig". In C++ if I use `next_permutation` it will only iterate through those 5 letters. So I'll get output such as; voidg, divgo, ovgid, etc.

This is so far my code as what is commonly suggested:

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Enter the string : ";
    cin >> str;
    sort(str.begin(), str.end()); 
    do {
        cout << str << endl;
    } while (next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()));
}
```

However I also want output that is less then 5, such as; void, divg, ovgi, dog, odg, oid, div, iv, go, do, etc. Is this even possible and if so how do I achieve this?

I've spent the last 12 hours trying to get something working to no avail and I'm starting to pull my hair out stressing.

Thank you all for the help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substr on every string returned by next_permutation to get the sub-strings. You can then use a set to aggregate all of the strings from all the permutations which would automatically handle duplicates for you. Something like this would work :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<unordered_set>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::unordered_set<std::string> permutations;

    std::cout << "Enter the string : ";
    std::cin >> str;
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    unsigned int length = str.length();
    do {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            permutations.insert(str.substr(0, length - i - 1));
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()));

    std::for_each(permutations.begin(), permutations.end(), [](std::string permutation) {
        std::cout << permutation << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works a treat and is what I want for most of the day. I've just added the `#include` statements to your answer, as it makes use of `<unordered_set>`.